# How to display logging info of pool.map to pyqt5 gui

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a very bad problem now, the logging info can't be updated to the gui properly, how can I make the logging info output of run_parallel(devices_info), show to the pyqt5 textBrowser, I think the reason is the pool.map, but I don't know how to solve it, thanks a lot

this is my tset code
https://github.com/marvel68/testdemo.git

```
import logging
import multiprocessing
import os
import sys
import time

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QObject, QThread
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget

BASE_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))

LOG_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_PATH, "log")
if not os.path.exists(LOG_PATH):
    os.mkdir(LOG_PATH)


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.setEnabled(True)
        Dialog.resize(1045, 648)
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(Dialog)
        self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 261, 1021, 371))
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        self.test_start = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.test_start.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(820, 10, 141, 51))
        self.test_start.setObjectName("test_start")
        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "textBrowser"))
        self.test_start.setText(_translate("Dialog", "start"))


class Handler(QObject, logging.Handler):
    new_record = pyqtSignal(object)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        super(logging.Handler).__init__()

    def emit(self, record):
        """输出格式可以按照自己的意思定义HTML格式"""
        record_dict = record.__dict__

        asctime = record_dict['asctime'] + " >> "
        line = record_dict['filename'] + " -> line:" + str(record_dict['lineno']) + " | "
        levelname = record_dict['levelname']
        message = record_dict['message']

        html = asctime + line + levelname + message
        time.sleep(0.5)

        self.new_record.emit(str(html))  
        QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()


class Logger():

    def __init__(self):
        self.logname = os.path.join(LOG_PATH, "{}.log".format(time.strftime("%Y%m%d")))
        self.logger = logging.getLogger("log")
        self.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

        self.formater = logging.Formatter(
            '[%(asctime)s][%(filename)s %(lineno)d][%(levelname)s]: %(message)s')

        self.filelogger = logging.FileHandler(self.logname, mode='a', encoding="UTF-8")
        self.console = logging.StreamHandler()

        self.console.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        self.filelogger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

        self.filelogger.setFormatter(self.formater)
        self.console.setFormatter(self.formater)

        self.logger.addHandler(self.filelogger)
        self.logger.addHandler(self.console)

    def get_log(self):
        return self.logger


Logger = Logger().logger


class Window(QWidget, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.thread = None
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.handler = Handler()
        Logger.addHandler(self.handler)
        Logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

        self.test_start.clicked.connect(self.buttonClick)
        self.handler.new_record.connect(self.write)

    def write(self, s):
        self.textBrowser.append(s)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()

    def buttonClick(self):
        self.textBrowser.clear()
        self.thread = Example()

        self.thread.start()


class Example(QThread):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        """
        进行任务操作，主要的逻辑操作,返回结果
        """
        run()


def run_parallel(devices_info):
    Logger.info(devices_info)
    for i in range(5):
        i = i + 1
        Logger.info(i)


def run():
    devices_info = [(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4)]
    Logger.info(devices_info)
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(5)
    pool.map(run_parallel, devices_info)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import cgitb

    cgitb.enable(format='text')
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = Window()
    # ui = Ui_Dialog()
    # ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Sorry but questions should be self-contained. Please [edit] your post and provide a [mre] (please read that link and follow its directions *very carefully*).

Comment: Here is my minimized code block, please check it out, thanks a lot